# Get branch name in Fastlane after merge

Tags: git, fastlane, cicd

I want to build a workflow in Fastlane, and I need the branch name of the branch that was just merged into main.

Example: Say I have branch `ABC-123`. Somebody created a pull request from `ABC-123` to `main`. After the merge, a workflow is run in which I want to get the branch name.

I've tried something like this:

```
lane :jiraNotify do
    branch = git_branch
    ticketIndex = branch.index("ABC")
    if ticketIndex != nil
        # publish changes
    end
end
```

My issue is that because this workflow is ran after the pull request was merged, the branch variable will always be `main`.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: You'll need to get this information *from the CI/CD system*. Git does not possess it. Note that getting the branch name isn't bad in and of itself, but you should not *use* the branch name as branch names are ephemeral. Have the CI/CD system deliver the *hash ID* to you; that's the reliable, permanent name for the commit.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to notify the Jira task that the build for that branch has been deployed. But indeed, it makes sense that branch names are ephemeral and maybe I have the wrong approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few possible approaches:

1. The branch name is passed from your repository provider (e.g. GitHub/GitLab) to your CI system (e.g. Jenkins, Travis…) which may make it available to fastlane as an environment variable. However, many *don't* make it available — you'll have to look at their docs. You can read environment variables inside fastlane using `ENV["SOME_ENV_VAR_NAME"]`.
2. Alternatively you can tell your team to include the JIRA ID in the commit message and extract it from there. You could do something like:

   ```rb
   commit = last_git_commit
   message = commit[:message]
   jira_id = message.split(' ')[0]
   ```
3. You could skip fastlane entirely and use [Jira Automation Triggers](https://support.atlassian.com/cloud-automation/docs/jira-automation-triggers/) to update the issue based on the `{{pullRequest.destinationBranch}}` smart value.